# V2 engine white smoke and not running very good

Tags: engine, stall, moped

I have a Gilera RCR moped with a V-twin engine. It's not very compact. I have run into a problem, it won't run when not moving and it has a lot of white smoke.

Could it be an engine problem?

Comment: This question is rather broad. Assuming this is a 2-cycle engine, did you verify the oil mix is correct? Water in the fuel? When it is moving, does it run properly?

Comment: Is this the same as your unit?  [SERVICE](http://scootergrisen.dk/scooterhjemmeside/download/gilera_smt_rcr_servicemanual.pdf)

Comment: I noticed the manual is a single and not a moped, Service manual has same name but not the same engine. There must be a sub model number.